# Django Compare ManyToMany fields

Tags: django, django-models

Let's say I have a model:

```py
class Group(models.Model):
    patients = models.ManyToManyField(Patient)
    patients_tracker = models.ManyToManyField(Patient, blank=True, editable=False, related_name="patient_tracker")
    ...
```

Now, in my overridden `save` function, I set both of them equal to each other. By doing:

```py
self.patients_tracker.set(self.patients.all()) #----Statement a
```

but in my post_save function,  this statement

```py
if instance.patients_tracker.all() != instance.patients.all(): #----Statement b
```

for some reason returns False even though I checked manually and `print(instance.patients_tracker.all())` & `print("Here's the patients: ", instance.patients.all())` return the same Patients in them which only tells me that "Statement a" worked perfectly.

But why doesn't "Statement b" work and return true? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: Let me actually be a bit more clearer about my intentions here:
I've search intensively all around and there are no Field Trackers or History Trackers for ManyToManyFields. What I want is to know when a Patient and which Patient is added or Removed in the `Group.patients` field. I figured I would try to manually do it but that didn't go so well, as you can see.

Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, So I figured it out after a little break.

Below we are comparing querysets which for some reason doesn't work.

```py
if instance.patients_tracker.all() != instance.patients.all(): #----Statement b
```

But if we just turn the queryset into a list by adding the python's built in "list()" function like so

```py
if list(instance.patients_tracker.all()) != list(instance.patients.all()):
```

And this works beautifully.
I was going to remove this question as this was such a stupid mistake on my part but decided to add an answer in-case someone searches for the same keywords as I did when Googling for an answer to this problem.